# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos \pi n}{2^n}$ converges by the comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos \pi n}{2^n}$$

How can I show whether or not the following series converges using the comparison test?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! In future, you can format mathematics on this site using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, note that $-1 ≤ \cos \pi n ≤ 1$, so you can compare this series with $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $-\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n$, 
$$
\bigg| \frac{\cos \pi n}{2^n}
\bigg| \leq \frac{1}{2^n}. 
$$

So 
$$
0\leq \bigg|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos \pi n}{2^n}\bigg|
\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \bigg|\frac{\cos \pi n}{2^n}\bigg|  
\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^n  
= \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 1 < \infty. 
$$
So the series converges.

Comment: What is the purpose of the $0 \le$ ?

Comment: @JackBauer I went back in and typed that in in order to be clear (be more explicit) to the OP that the series is indeed bounded above and below. Also, some analysts write them out explicitly in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: $$|\cos(\pi n)| \le 1$$

Hint 2:

> $$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{2^n} < \infty$$